# javascript - How to keep input data after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

I'm having some difficulty keeping different values ​​after refreshing the page. I found an old code on github and I wanted to modify it to make it better. In practice, the program creates a shopping list where I can highlight (if bought) or delete the inserted product but every time I refresh the page the values ​​entered disappear.

This is the program:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var leftbutton = '<img class="check" src="image/approve.png" alt="check" title="click to mark purchase" width="30px">'
var rightbutton = '<img class="close" src="image/close.png" alt="close" title="click to remove item" width="30px>">'

$('.textinput').keydown(function(a) {
    if (a.keyCode == 13) {
        $('.list').prepend('<div class="result">' + leftbutton + '<p>' + $('.add-items').val() + '</p>' + rightbutton + '</div>');
    $('input.add-items').val("");
    }
})

 $('.list').on('click', '.check', function() {
    if ($(this).closest('.list > div').hasClass('result')) {
        $(this).closest('.list > div').addClass( 'result-remove' );
        $(this).closest('.list > div').removeClass( 'result' );

    }   
    else {
        $(this).closest('.list > div').removeClass( 'result-remove' );
        $(this).closest('.list > div').addClass( 'result' );
    }
    });

  $('.list').on('click', '.close', function() {
        $(this).closest('.list > div').fadeOut("fast")

    });
});
```

Comment: JavaScript is state less so you need to apply cookie or localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a session variable like:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("variableName", variableValue);
```

and retrieve them by calling like:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("variableName");
```

So logically speaking, set session variable value on your input's key up event and on page Load get your session value and print it in it's place. I am sure in the same way you can store stringified objects in the variable and retrieve them by parsing back.

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: sessionStorage has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: You can use it within jquery and that can serve your purpose. There is localStorage also:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a variable that'll be saved is using localStorage.getItem and localStorage.setItem;

```
<input id="saveField" placeholder="0" type="number"></input>
<button onclick="load()">load</button>
<button onclick="save()">save</button>
<script>
var saveValue;
function load(){
saveValue = localStorage.getItem("saveValue");
document.getElementById("saveField").value = saveValue;
};
function save(){
saveValue = document.getElementById("saveField").value;
localStorage.setItem("saveValue", saveValue);
};</script>
```